# Como ler arquivo txt com datasets composto por múltiplas dimensões?

Tags: r, dataset

estou com um arquivo com datasets composto por múltiplas dimensões num só txt. Por exemplo,

```
2 3 #dimensao do primeiro dataset
1 2 3
4 5 6
4 4 #dimensao do segundo dataset
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Como ler esses dados e formar datasets diferentes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A seguinte função faz o que quer, pelo menos com os dados da pergunta. Tentei fazer a função o mais geral possível mas nunca se sabe.

```
ler_txt <- function(file, path = "."){
  if(path != "."){
    old_dir <- setwd(path)
    on.exit(setwd(old_dir))
  }
  txt <- readLines(file)
  txt <- txt[nchar(txt) > 0]
  nlinhas <- length(txt)
  linha <- 1
  out_list <- list()
  while(linha < nlinhas){
    dims <- scan(text = txt[linha])
    out <- matrix(NA, nrow = dims[1], ncol = dims[2])
    for(i in seq_len(dims[1])){
      out[i, ] <- scan(text = txt[linha + i])
    }
    linha <- linha + dims[1] + 1L
    out_list[[length(out_list) + 1]] <- out
  }
  out_list
}

ler_txt(file = "dados.txt")
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    4    5    6
#
#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4
#[2,]    5    6    7    8
#[3,]    9   10   11   12
#[4,]   13   14   15   16
```